# How to use TrackBy in reactive form

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form with data from api. The form contains a table with 4 inputs which reflects the contents of an array. The array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 15706,
    "CertificateId": 126,
    "IsEmpty": true,
    "Period": {
      "Value": "2021-12-15T00:00:00"
    },
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 12,
    "WorkedHoursAmount": null,
    "AbsenceAmount": null,
    "OverTimeAmount": null,
    "MoreTimeAmount": null,
    "IgnoreWarning": false
  },
  {
    "Id": 15707,
    "CertificateId": 126,
    "IsEmpty": true,
    "Period": {
      "Value": "2021-11-15T00:00:00"
    },
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 11,
    "WorkedHoursAmount": null,
    "AbsenceAmount": null,
    "OverTimeAmount": null,
    "MoreTimeAmount": null,
    "IgnoreWarning": false
  },
  {
    "Id": 15708,
    "CertificateId": 126,
    "IsEmpty": true,
    "Period": {
      "Value": "2021-10-15T00:00:00"
    },
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 10,
    "WorkedHoursAmount": null,
    "AbsenceAmount": null,
    "OverTimeAmount": null,
    "MoreTimeAmount": null,
    "IgnoreWarning": false
  }
]
```

I'm using the formArray (HoursList) in the table like this:

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      HoursList: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.initHoursListArray();

 initHoursListArray() {
   for (let row of this.HoursList) {
     let HoursFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
       Id: new FormControl(row?.Id),
       CertificateId: new FormControl(row?.CertificateId),
       Year: new FormControl(row?.Year),
       IsEmpty: new FormControl(row?.IsEmpty),
       Month: new FormControl(row?.Month),
       WorkedHoursAmount: new FormControl(row?.WorkedHoursAmount),
       AbsenceAmount: new FormControl(row?.AbsenceAmount),
       OverTimeAmount: new FormControl(row?.OverTimeAmount),
       MoreTimeAmount: new FormControl(row?.MoreTimeAmount),
       Period: this.initPeriodFormGroup(row.Period),
     });

     this.HoursList.push(HoursFormGroup);
   }
```

The inputs formcontrols are from these propertys:  "WorkedHoursAmount",
"AbsenceAmount","OverTimeAmount", "MoreTimeAmount"

When changing value on any of these the value are being saved to database. I'm saving the whole formarray to database even if I just change one input (if thats worth knowing).

**The Problem**
I have to use trackBy function like this to prevent lost of focus when changing values:

```
*ngFor="let row of form.get('HoursList')['controls'];;
            let i = index;
            trackBy: trackByFn"
```

But this gives me problems when saving values to database because I dont get the correct values from inputs. It sometimes works and sometimes dont.Usually I get the old value.

I have tryed :

```
trackByFn(index: number, cert: any) {
    return index;
  }
```

And returning item (or cert in this case) but nothing works..Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Are you using a form array? Include this code in your question

Answer (score 0):

If the order of items in your hours list array changes then just using the index in your trackby function is unstable. It looks like you have an ID field - what happens if you return that from your trackby function?

Comment: Hmm Item returns a formGroup, should I then do "return item.value.Id"?